# SSO React Login, without 3rd party libraries

Tags: reactjs, azure, single-sign-on

I have a site (React) which will open with a button an external page (similar to Microsoft Azure, but it is not). I have to login there, after the login, the page redirects to a "return_uri" that I previously configured, but now, how, in my React web page, I will know that that specific user is the one who is accesing the site?

I was watching this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pH5spE2Yss

but there he is using a npm library to to the work of comunicate both Azure and the page, and if the `async` call fails, it is not logged, but if it works, is logged, but seems not as the real world. I'm pretty confused of to handle this SSO Login, because the cloud has very few documentation (it's a private cloud, similar to Azure).

Any hint?

Comment: no matter which cloud you're using the process is the same. Front end will receive a jwt token, and you'll pass on each request. The backend of your app will receive the token, and validate against the IDP (identity provider)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that the sso server returns a redirect_url with a ?code in the URI, with that code I can call another API to get a token and so on. Thanks